Incomplete display of arrows in MobaXterm
I enabled zsh on the server, and when I connect to the server using MobaXterm locally, I noticed that the arrow symbols in the shell prompt are not displayed completely.
Screenshot of the abnormal arrow display is as follows:

The Terminal configuration information for MobaXterm is as follows：

But when I connect to the server using Windows Terminal, the arrow symbols in the shell prompt are displayed correctly.
Screenshot of the normal arrow display is as follows：

I suspect there might be a misconfiguration in MobaXterm. Who can help me?
I tried modifying the Terminal configuration in MobaXterm, but it didn't have any effect. Note: The font settings in my MobaXterm Terminal are exactly the same as in Windows Terminal.
